# Showing a function increasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was solving exercises from the book [Real Analysis by Carothers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521497566). I am having trouble in solving Problem 36 of Exercise of chapter 2 on page 33. I am actually very poor in producing $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments and I guess the problem may need this kind of arguments. Please help me. Thnx in advance.

Here is the problem.

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be an increasing function and let $\{x_n\}$ be an enumeration of discontinuities of $f$. Define, for all $n$, $a_n = f(x_n)-f(x_n-) \text{ and } a_n=0 \text{ if }x_n=a $, $b_n = f(x_n+)-f(x_n) \text{ and } b_n=0 \text{ if }x_n=b $ Now define $h(x)= \sum_{x_n\le x}a_n+ \sum_{x_n< x}b_n$ . Show that $h$ is increasing and $f-h$ is both continuous and increasing.

Now frankly speaking I am very little comfortable with $f(x_n+),f(x_n-)$ notations and there are so much information in the question , I am puzzled from where I should start. I am not finding a way. I am completely stuck.

I apologise for not showing a good effort from my end. I am really sorry.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: First thing, can you show that $a_n \geqslant 0$ and $b_n \geqslant 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: It is intuitively clear to me because I guess $a_n$ and $b_n$ are so called "jumps" and they are non negative because $f$ is increasing. But I may not give a rigorous  proof

Comment: Okay. Although you say you're not very comfortable with it, you need to know what $f(x_n^-)$ and $f(x_n^+)$ mean. We have $$f(x_n^-) = \lim_{\substack{x\to x_n \\ x < x_n}} f(x)\quad \text{and} \quad f(x_n^+) = \lim_{\substack{x\to x_n \\ x > x_n}} f(x).$$ Now you need to see that $f$ being increasing means $f(x_n^-) \leqslant f(x_n) \leqslant f(x_n^+)$. Can you prove that?

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I can prove what you stated. Since $x<x_n$ and $f$ increasing, $f(x)\le f(x_n)$ and then it follows from taking limit. Am I correct?

Comment: Right. So we now know that the $a_n$ and $b_n$ are non-negative. From that, you can easily deduce that $h$ is increasing (non-strictly). How?

Comment: I think it is because if $y\ge x$ then there may be some discontinuities after $x$ but before $y$ and we are adding corresponding $a_n,b_n$ (in addition to what we had for $x$). And since we know $a_n,b_n$ are non negative, $f(x)\le f(y)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Once $h$ is increasing, $f-h$ should be increasing as this is difference of two increasing functions. Am I correct?

Comment: Right, if $x < y$, then $$h(y) - h(x) = \sum_{x < x_n \leqslant y} a_n + \sum_{x \leqslant x_n < y} b_n \geqslant 0.$$ But the difference of two increasing functions need in general not be increasing. On $[0,2]$, consider $g(x) = x$ and $\tilde{g}(x) = x^2$. Both are increasing, but $x \mapsto x - x^2$ isn't increasing. Here, we have a special situation.

Comment: I see, difference of two increasing functions may not be increasing.  Then what will be our argument to show f-h increasing? I mean what is the special situation you mentioned? I can not figure it out.

Comment: @DanielFischer Your hints are proving very useful for me. Thank you so much. But I have to go offline now. I am keen to get the ideas from you. Will you please post the rest of the steps/hints (with some details please) so that I can solve the problem when I return. I am really sorry for this kind of request. It will be very helpful for me. Thanx again.

Comment: Okay, I will write an answer giving an outline.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments we found out that we have $a_n \geqslant 0$ and $b_n \geqslant 0$ for all $n$, since $f$ is increasing. If $x < x_n$ we have $f(x) \leqslant f(x_n)$ by the monotonicity, and then

$$f(x_n^-) = \lim_{\substack{x\to x_n \\ x < x_n}} f(x) = \sup \{ f(x) : x < x_n\}$$

follows. Then the monotonicity of $h$ follows easily: for $x < y$ we have

$$h(y) - h(x) = \Biggl(\sum_{x_n \leqslant y} a_n + \sum_{x_n < y} b_n\Biggr) - \Biggl(\sum_{x_n \leqslant x} a_n + \sum_{x_n < x} b_n\Biggr) = \sum_{x < x_n \leqslant y} a_n + \sum_{x \leqslant x_n < y} b_n \geqslant 0.$$

Now it remains to show that $g := f - h$ is continuous and increasing.

For the continuity, note that $g$ is continuous at $x\in (a,b)$ if and only if

$$\lim_{\substack{y \to x \\ y < x}} g(y) = g(x^-) = g(x) = g(x^+) = \lim_{\substack{y\to x \\ y > x}} g(y),$$

and it is continuous at $a$ if and only if $g(a^+) = g(a)$, and at $b$ if and only if $g(b^-) = g(b)$.

In particular, all the one-sided limits must exist. But the one-sided limits of $\varphi$ exist at every point of the domain of $\varphi$ if $\varphi$ is a monotonic function (increasing or decreasing), and if the one-sided limits $\varphi(x^+)$ and $\psi(x^+)$ exist for two functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ defined at least on $[x,x+\delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$, then the right limit of $\varphi - \psi$ at $x$ exists and $(\varphi - \psi)(x^+) = \varphi(x^+) - \psi(x^+)$. The analogous assertion holds for left limits, of course. So we know that all one-sided limits of $g$ exist, and we need to check whether we have $g(x^-) = g(x) = g(x^+)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ (where we define $g(a^-) = g(a)$ and $g(b^+) = g(b)$ so that the chain of equations makes sense also for these $x$). But

$$g(x^+) - g(x) = \bigl(f(x^+) - h(x^+)\bigr) - \bigl(f(x) - h(x)\bigr) = \bigl(f(x^+) - f(x)\bigr) - \bigl(h(x^+) - h(x)\bigr),$$

and similarly for the left limits, so the continuity of $f - h$ is equivalent to the equalities $f(x^+) - f(x) = h(x^+) - h(x)$ and $f(x) - f(x^-) = h(x) - h(x^-)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Thus you need to show $h(x_n) - h(x_n^-) = a_n$ and $h(x_n^+) - h(x_n) = b_n$ for all $n$, and $h(x^-) = h(x) = h(x^+)$ for all $x$ that are none of the $x_n$ (for the points of continuity of $f$). It might be helpful to split $h$ into

$$h_r(x) = \sum_{x_n \leqslant x} a_n\quad \text{and} \quad h_l(x) = \sum_{x_n < x} b_n.$$

Finally, to show that $f - h$ is increasing, you need to show that for $x < y$ we have

$$f(y) - f(x) \geqslant h(y) - h(x).$$

We know $h(y) - h(x)$ from above, and to show the inequality, it is useful to note that since $f$ is increasing, we have, for all partitions $x = t_0 < t_1 < \dotsc < t_{k-1} < t_k = y$,

$$f(y) - f(x) = \sum_{\kappa = 1}^k \bigl(f(t_\kappa) - f(t_{\kappa - 1})\bigr).$$

A judiciously chosen sequence of partitions helps establishing the inequality using

$$\sum_{x < x_n \leqslant y} a_n = \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{\substack{x < x_n \leqslant y \\ n \leqslant m}} a_n$$

and the similar limit for the other sum.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will try to complete the proof.